# I have 7 col-md-1 and 1 col-md-2. How do I get rid of the space between the last item and the one before?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want to get rid of the uneven space between download and contact us.
I've posted a photo below of how my code looks right now live.

```
<div class="row" align="center" >
                     <div class="col-md-1"><a>System</a></div>
                     <div class="col-md-1"><a>Technology</a></div>
                     <div class="col-md-1"><a>Testimonial</a></div>
                     <div class="col-md-1"><a>About</a></div>
                     <div class="col-md-1"><a>Careers</a></div>
                     <div class="col-md-1"><a>News</a></div>
                     <div class="col-md-1"><a>Downloads</a></div>
                     <div class="col-md-2"><a>Contact Us</a></div>
                 </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Not sure if this what you need but you can add "text-left" to your last div to have "less space" between the last two items. (taking the @Webber Codepen : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QBNEKV )

Comment: why are you not using the bootstrap nav component which takes care of all this?

Answer (score 0):

Your text is aligned to the center of each div.

There is no space between the divs; there is only space after your last column.

Class `.col-md-2` will take up 2 columns, making it look like there is space between the divs, but if you put a border around each div, you will see that this is actually not the case;

See this **[codepen](https://codepen.io/webbertakken/pen/GBZqBx)** displaying the described effect.

You have a few options to do what you want:

- Giving all columns the same class (i.e. col-md-1) (See potential fix 1)
- Using flex to put space around or between each element (See potential fix 2)

  - *Note that Bootstrap v4 does this using the `nav-justified` class on the container.*
- Using flex to have each element grow respectively to their size (See potential fix 3)

  - *Note that Bootstrap v4 does this using the `nav-fill` class on the container.*
- Using `text-left` class to position the anchor in the div (See @Neyt comment)

Answer (score 0):

Move columns to the right using .offset-md-* classes. These classes increase the left margin of a column by * columns. For example, .offset-md-4 moves .col-md-4 over four columns.

In addition to column clearing at responsive breakpoints, you may need to reset offsets.

More information https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#offset-classes

Answer (score -1):

You could give the last column a class of col-md-1.

Why have you given it a class of col-md-2?

Answer (score -1):

You are using rows and columns for what looks to be a nav, if so you should really be using a bootstrap nav or navbar construct.

Also, are you using Bootstrap 3 or 4?

There are a number of ways to implement navs in BS4, here is a snippet showing a few using a Bootstrap 4 Nav with different spacing modifiers, run in full page mode:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<nav class="nav">
  <a class="nav-link" href="#">System</a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Technology</a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Testimonial</a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Careers</a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="#">News</a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Downloads</a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Us</a>
</nav>

<nav class="nav nav-fill">
  <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">System</a>
  <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Technology</a>
  <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Testimonial</a>
  <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">About</a>
  <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Careers</a>
  <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">News</a>
  <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Downloads</a>
  <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Contact Us</a>
</nav>

<nav class="nav nav-justified">
  <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">System</a>
  <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Technology</a>
  <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Testimonial</a>
  <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">About</a>
  <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Careers</a>
  <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">News</a>
  <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Downloads</a>
  <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Contact Us</a>
</nav>
```